# .NET Link Button only fires once

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I'm experiencing a strange issue with a form I've created for an old .NET webforms site. Essentially, I have a linkbutton which forwards the user to another page:

```
 protected void callumTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Response.Redirect(ThankYouUrl);
    }
```

Button for reference

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="callumTest" runat="server" OnClick="callumTest_Click">Callum Test</asp:LinkButton>
```

What I'm seeing is the following. The button will successfully fire once as expected. If I then navigate back to the previous page and try to fire the button again..nothing happens. The page posts back but the event is never hit. If I then wait for a few minutes and try again...the button works. Navigating back and trying again results in the button breaking..again.

I've tried to replicate this on a local environment and cannot. This is only happening when the code is deployed up to server level. I've tried rebuilding the form from scratch, this does not resolve the issue. As well as regenerating the OnClick through design view.

I'm really stumped by this!

Comment: Hi,

Just to clarify, I'm going back to the previous page by manually entering the URL, I'm avoiding using the back button.

Comment: What happens when you set a breakpoint in the `callumTest_Click` event and try the same test?

Comment: Hi Lews,

The breakpoint is never hit. I have tried adding logging also to verify this. It's almost as if the event isn't bound to the button. However, if I wait a period of time, say a couple of minutes, the event fires?

So to clarify:

1. I visit the page for the first time and the button fires correctly
2. I go back to the page manually by entering the URL and try to fire the button and nothing happens
3. I wait a couple of minutes and try the button again and it works?

Comment: This sounds like some kind of browser caching issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any `JavaScript` that might be cancelling the event on the client, thus never reaching the server? Are you getting any console errors after going back to the URL?

Also, how does `ThankYouUrl` get its value?

Could you try adding the redirect on the client code and see what happens?

**JavaScript**

```
function RedirectMe () {
   window.location.href = '<%= ThankYouUrl %>';
}
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="callumTest" runat="server" OnClientClick="RedirectMe()">Callum Test</asp:LinkButton>
```